# Docker Service Separation

Tags: php, nginx, docker, containers, docker-compose

I am not sure how to separate the services on my server properly with docker. I have an application written in NodeJS and two applications written in PHP. I use NGINX as a webserver/reverse-proxy and MySQL as my database. I am not quite sure which docker container should handle which task and where to store the application files (js, php, static content like css and jpg).

---

I have the following options in mind (ommiting the MySQL container). Each rectangle is a docker image (except the 'Server' and the 'Server FS' rectangle).

**Option 1:** One NGINX container handling static content and passing requests to PHP-FPM and NodeJS. The application files are mounted into the docker images.

[image: Option 1]

**Option 2:** One NGINX container acting as a reverse proxy that bundles the different services. The applications itself are more portable since each application handles its own configuration (like route rewriting and handling static content).

[image: Option 2]

**Option 3:** One NGINX container acting as a reverse proxy as in Option 2. For each PHP application the NGINX webserver and the PHP-FPM module are contained in one docker image.

[image: Option 3]

**Option 4:** One NGINX container acting again as a reverse proxy. The application files are bundled within the respective docker images.

[image]

---

Is there a best practise how to separate the services into docker images? Option 4 seems to be the most portable and easiest deployable since the application files are contained in the image. Option 1 to 3 are easier to use in development since the images do not need to rebuild everytime the files change. Option 3 seems to be the best option to me but I also know that one docker container should only contain one service (either PHP-FPM **or** NGINX).

Is there a best practise or is it everybodies own decision how he/she wants to handle it. I would like to know about your experiences.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. *This is a reason to close the question on Stack Overflow*. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I disagree. This question is really well phrased with clear diagrams. I'm sure it will be helpful to people searching SO. Most of the questions in SO are already of the type "what's the best way to do this". Answers are typically based on experience.

Comment: "What is the best way to do this?" questions have long been debated on Stack Overflow. As a matter of course these kinds of questions are considered to have answers which are opinion based and that is a specific close reason here on Stack @Alkaline Most of the questions on Stack are much more specific and consider coding problems rather than how-to's.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming for a production system I would suggest diagram 1.

It will allow you to scale your services (nodejs, php-fpm) horizontally and it can provide some failover. It's also the way it would be architected with a cluster manager like Swarm or Kubernetes. You shouldn't need more than one nginx per host in your scenario.